# How to calculate Alpha and Beta values for QAOA Max-cut problem manually?

Tags: programming, quantum-algorithms, qaoa

I'm new to Quantum Computing. I came across solving the Max-cut problem using QAOA. For example, if I have a $U3$ gate with parameters $U3(0,0, \gamma_{XYZ})$ gamma parameter at $p=X$ between logical qubit Y and Z; and $Rz(\beta_X)$ beta parameter at $p=X$, how do I calculate the values of $\gamma$ and $\beta$?

Comment: What do you mean by *parameter at $p=X$*?

Comment: Hi @MartinVesely, Cirq has such a constraint that I'm not aware of. I have attached the link ([QAOA_cirq](https://quantumai.google/cirq/tutorials/qaoa)) where they have the value of p as 1 in Cirq for constructing QAOA.